# Oracle Database Continuous Query Notification in a multiple cluster environment

Tags: java, oracle, database-trigger, query-notifications

We want to implement Oracle Database Continuous Query Notification in a multiple cluster environment . But what we desire is that the DB change notification should be sent to only one instance of the application , because as of now it sending the change notification to all of the instance.
How do I get the desired characteristic.
My listener code is as

```
 DCNDemoListener list = new DCNDemoListener(this);
            dcr.addListener(list);

            // second step: add objects in the registration:
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // associate the statement with the registration:
            ((OracleStatement)stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from testtable where ID=1");
```

Properties :

```
OracleConnection conn = connect();

        // first step: create a registration on the server:
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS,"true");
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION,"true");
        DatabaseChangeRegistration dcr = conn.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(prop);
```